# Measurability of an absolutely continuous random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $X^n:= X_1^n,...,X_n^n$ be a sequence of $E^n$ valued random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Define $Y^n$ as a selection on $X^n$. Meaning $\mathbb{P}(Y^n=X_i^n|X^n=x)=p_i^n(x)$ with $\sum_i p_i^n(x) =1$. Is it immediate that $Y^n$ is $\mathcal{F}^n=\sigma(X^n)$ measurable? Is it the case for all the $Y^n$ defined like this? for all the $Y^n$ absolutely continuous wrt $X^n$? How can i prove it formally?

EDIT (updating progessively): @justt gave me some more insight. The selection process just needs to be independant from $X^n$. Turning the focus of the question on how to accomplish that.

Context: I want to select a random (following a given law) entry in a $n$ sized random tab. And I want to show that the selection process is measurable wrt to the law of the tab. I don't really know where to start, usually measurability is swept under the table...

Comment: When you say that $Y$ is a second random variable, is $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{F})\to E$? In that case $Y$ would be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable as a random variable, *without* making any reference to $X$. If you do not know whether $Y$ is measurable, then $\mathbb{P}_Y$ need not be well defined, so the question may not make sense in that case. Am I understanding correctly? Could you please clarify these things?

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I edited and expanded the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want your selection procedure to be independent of the sequence $X^n$, which is very likely the case, you need to introduce additional randomness (the random index $I^n$). So no $Y^n$ is not going to be $\sigma(X^n)$-measurable, but rather $\sigma(X^n,I^n)$-measurable.

Your answer makes it look like you are conflating the notion of measurability of a random variable wrt another, and absolute continuity between the law of a random variable and the law of another. These notions have nothing in common and are completely orthogonal (neither implies the other).

Comment: I think I'm starting to wrap my head around this. I guess my real question is how do i properly introduce the additional randomness? Correct me if i'm wrong, I need to first define a selection procedure on vectors of $E^n$, which would be a rv that would return a coordinate of $x\in E^n$ depending on $x$.  But i fail to see how i should write this rv properly to be independent of $X^n$ if the selection process depends on the contents of $X^n$ for example

Comment: But do you want it to depend on the content of $X^n$ ? The basic idea would be to define $I^n$ a random variable in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ independent of $X^n$ and setting $Y = X^n_{I^n}$. For that you need to consider the enlarged probability space $(\Omega \times \{1,\ldots,n\}, \mathcal F \otimes \mathcal P(\{1,\ldots,n\}))$.

Comment: I want to define variables like $Y^n = max_i X_i^n$, I don't want just the index in a vacuum. The dependancy is fine. I just want $Y^n$ to be adapted...

Comment: Ooooh so not independent then. Sure, the max functional is measurable, no problem about that. And any selection process that just looks at the data would work, i.e. if $I^n \in \sigma(X^n)$ then $Y = X^n_{I^n} \in \sigma(X_n)$.

Comment: But then what did you mean with $\mathbb{P}(Y^n=X_i^n)=p_i^n$ with $\sum_i p_i^n =1$ ? You can't specify the law of the random index independently of the data if the random index depends on the data...

Comment: Actually, yes it is fine if it depends on the data and I lose the independance. The $\mathbb{P}(Y^n=X_i^n)=p_i^n$ is a probality on $x$. A more accurate way of writing it would be: $\mathbb{P}(Y^n=X_i^n|X^n=x)=p_i^n(x)$ with $\sum_i p_i^n(x) =1$. I realized what I needed is for $Y^n$ to be $X^n$ measurable. So I guess my final question would be "Are all selection laws on $X^n$, $X^n$ measurable and can I write a formal proof of this fact?" Anyway, thank you enough for your help!

Comment: Ooohkay, so now you are describing the most general setting, because *any random variable $Y^n$ can be specified like this*.

Then there is *no way* $Y^n$ can be made $X^n$-measurable unless $p^n(x)$ is a dirac measure for all $x$, that is if $p_i^n(x) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $i,x$.

Comment: The $\max$ verifies this later condition.